# Android app on android 4.1.2- gets weird layout

Tags: android, layout

Im creating an android app it works great on android 4.2+
But when im trying to run it on android 4.1 and older it gets a weird layout 
I looked for it on the internet but couldn't find a fix for this.
This issue seems to appear only on android 4.1.2 and lower but on android 4.2.2 it works great.
Any ideas?

Screenshots:
**Android 4.2+**

[image]

**Android 4.1 and lower**

[image]

My layout xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/back"
              android:weightSum="1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkboxer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textview"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="363dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mobile"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="work"
            android:id="@+id/work"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="other"
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:layout_below="@+id/work"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <WebView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="@drawable/trans"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:background="#5ea2ff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:background="#58ff57"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:autoText="true"
         android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="102dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.19"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
            android:text="@string/edit" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoText="true" 
        android:enabled="false"
            android:editable="false" 
        android:background="@drawable/trans"
        android:textColor="#ff0008" />

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:background="@drawable/enter" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Input"
            android:id="@+id/button" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText" 
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#a3ffbb" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/menubutton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe show us some layout code?

Comment: Oh sure sorry i forget thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `layout_alignParentStart` and `layout_alignParentEnd` and those attributes weren't introduced until Android 4.2 (API 17). You need to stick to older top, bottom, left, and right align parent attributes or find another anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, it's not only **layout_alignParentStart** or **layout_alignParentEnd** , all the **Start/End** layout parameters crash on Android 4.1.2 devices (**marginStart**/**marginEnd** , **paddingStart**/**paddingEnd**... ).
Just changing them for **Left**/**Right** works fine, but forget about RTL compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I use this attribute "layout_alignParentStart" in my app's ImageButton with in layout xml. And find it work well on most devices but crash on the oppo x907. But according to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html it'will not lead to a crash. So I think it's sometimes because some special devices don't have a good compatible.